# homomorphism from a ring R to the quotient ring R/I

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$ and $I$ be an ideal. There is a natural homomorphism from $R$ to the quotient ring $R/I$ which maps $r$ to $r+I$. Is there any other homomorphism from $R$ to $R/I$?

Comment: What have you tried?   What does it take to be a homomorphism?  Hint:   Is there always a homomorphism of a certian type?

Comment: thank you. homomorphism here is as Atyiah's book and maps 1 to 1. so 0 is not  homomorphism. i dont know any other homomorphism of a certain type.

Comment: Which examples have you tried? "Homomorphism as in Atiyah's book" is not a precise statement, there are group homomorphisms, module homomorphisms, ring homomorphisms, etc etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\pi: R \rightarrow R/I$ be the canonical ring homomorphism. If $R/I$ has a nontrivial endomorphism $\phi:R/I \rightarrow R/I$, then $\pi$ and $\phi\circ\pi$ are two *distinct* ring homomorphisms from $R$ to $R/I$. Indeed $\phi$ being nontrivial means that there is some $x+I$ with $\phi(x+I)\neq x+I$. Since $x+I$ is just another notation for $\pi(x)$ this shows our claim.

One example is given by $R=\Bbb C\times \Bbb C$, $I=\Bbb C \times \{0\}$ and $\phi:\Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C, x \mapsto \overline x$.

Comment: thank you,+1 very helpful

Comment: You are welcome. Feel free to accept :)